# Transform single-cell list of values to HTML

Tags: excel

I have cells that are in the format of:

**key:value|key1:value1|key2:value2|etc...**

The number of keys in each cell will vary from 0 to 10.

I need to transform that cell into a simple HTML table, for example:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Key1</td>
            <td>Value2</td>
        </tr>
        ... etc
    </table>
```

Is this possible in using calculations, or do I need to be looking at a Macro? At a glance I did not see any functions designed to split strings using a delimiter, so it looks like it will be pretty cumbersome to do in a calculation, if not impossible. A calculation would be preferred though for this, if practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it can be done in a formula with a lot of helper columns, but what a mess it would be.  Here's some VBA that will do what you want.

```
Public Function KeyValueToHtml(ByVal sKeyValue As String) As String

    Dim vaPipe As Variant
    Dim vaColon As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aReturn() As String

    vaPipe = Split(sKeyValue, "|")
    ReDim aReturn(LBound(vaPipe) To UBound(vaPipe))

    For i = LBound(vaPipe) To UBound(vaPipe)
        vaColon = Split(vaPipe(i), ":")
        aReturn(i) = Tag(Tag(vaColon(0), "td") & vbNewLine & Tag(vaColon(1), "td"), "tr", , True)
    Next i

    KeyValueToHtml = Tag(Join(aReturn, vbNewLine), "table", , True)

End Function

Function Tag(ByVal sValue As String, ByVal sTag As String, _
    Optional ByVal sAttr As String = "", Optional ByVal bIndent As Boolean = False) As String

    Dim sReturn As String

    If Len(sAttr) > 0 Then
        sAttr = Space(1) & sAttr
    End If

    If bIndent Then
        sValue = vbTab & Replace(sValue, vbNewLine, vbNewLine & vbTab)
        sReturn = "<" & sTag & sAttr & ">" & vbNewLine & sValue & vbNewLine & "</" & sTag & ">"
    Else
        sReturn = "<" & sTag & sAttr & ">" & sValue & "</" & sTag & ">"
    End If

    Tag = sReturn

End Function
```